# jq - subtracting one array from another using a single command

Tags: arrays, json, sorting, split, jq

I have three operations with jq to get the right result. How can I do it within one command?
Here is a fragment from the source JSON file

```
[
    {
        "Header": {
            "Tenant": "tenant-1",
            "Rcode": 200
        },
        "Body": {
            "values": [
                {
                    "id": "0b0b-0c0c",
                    "name": "NumberOfSearchResults"
                },
                {
                    "id": "aaaa0001-0a0a",
                    "name": "LoadTest"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "Header": {
            "Tenant": "tenant-2",
            "Rcode": 200
        },
        "Body": {
            "values": []
        }
    },
    {
        "Header": {
            "Tenant": "tenant-3",
            "Rcode": 200
        },
        "Body": {
            "values": [
                {
                    "id": "cccca0003-0b0b",
                    "name": "LoadTest"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "Header": {
            "Tenant": "tenant-4",
            "Rcode": 200
        },
        "Body": {
            "values": [
                {
                    "id": "0f0g-0e0a",
                    "name": "NumberOfSearchResults"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

I apply two filters and create two intermediate JSON files. First I create the list of all tenants

```
jq -r '[.[].Header.Tenant]' source.json >all-tenants.json
```

And then I select to create an array of all tenants not having a particular key present in the `Body.values[]` array:

```
jq -r '[.[] | select (all(.Body.values[]; .name !="LoadTest")  )  ] | [.[].Header.Tenant]' source.json >filter1.json
```

Results - all-tenants.json

```
["tenant-1",
"tenant-2",
"tenant-3",
"tenant-4"
]
```

filter1.json

```
["tenant-2",
"tenant-4"
]
```

And then I substruct filter1.json from all-tenants.json to get the difference:

```
jq  -r -n --argfile filter filter1.json --argfile alltenants all-tenants.json '$alltenants - $filter|.[]'
```

Result:

```
tenant-1
tenant-3
```

Tenant names - values for the "Tenant" key are unique and each of them occurs only once in the source.json file.

Just to clarify - I understand that I can have a select condition(s) that would give me the same resut as subtracting two arrays.

What I want to understand - how can I assign and use these two arrays into vars directly in a single command not involving the intermediate files?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I assign and use these two arrays into vars directly in a single command not involving the intermediate files?

Simply store the intermediate arrays as jq "$-variables":

```
[.[].Header.Tenant] as $x
| ([.[] | select (all(.Body.values[]; .name !="LoadTest")  )  ] | [.[].Header.Tenant]) as $y
| $x - $y
```

If you want to itemize the contents of $x - $y, then simply add a final `.[]` to the pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

Use your filters to fill in the values of a new object and use the keys to refer to the arrays.

```
jq -r '{
         "all-tenants": [.[].Header.Tenant],
         "filter1": [.[]|select (all(.Body.values[]; .name !="LoadTest"))]|[.[].Header.Tenant]
       } | .["all-tenants"] - .filter1 | .[]'
```

Note: .["all-tenants"] is required by the special character "-" in that key. See the entry under [Object Identifier-Index](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Basicfilters) in the manual.

Comment: This is the first time I see `select(all(...; ...))`; truly an idiom.

Comment: Thanks, so in essence, your solution is to create a new object with two arrays inside and then subtract one from another, correct? If so, is creating additional objects an unnecessary operation?

Comment: That's right. You need to refer to your two arrays. Assigning them to $-variables is one way to do it: you refer to the arrays using the assigned $-variable. Using the key-value structure of an object is another: you refer to the arrays using the assigned keys. You need to make an object for the second solution to work and you need to create variables for the first solution to work.